# Weird behavior of big.NewInt anonymous variable

Tags: go

In the code snippet below, I want to make a very simple calculation `d = a + b + c; a, b, c = b, c, d`. It iterates several times.

In the first try, I make an anonymous variable `big.NewInt(0).Add(a, b)` to get the result of `a + b`, then add it and `c` to get the final result of `a + b + c`. But from the second iteration, `d.Add(big.NewInt(0).Add(a, b), c)` changed the value of `c`, then `b`, then `a`, and of course, the final result is wrong.

However, the second try's method gave me the right answer. Can anyone tell me why, please?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    // first try
    a := big.NewInt(1)
    b := big.NewInt(2)
    c := big.NewInt(3)
    d := big.NewInt(0)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        // d = a + b + c
        d.Add(big.NewInt(0).Add(a, b), c)
        fmt.Println(a, b, c, d)
        // a <- b, b <- c, c <- d
        a, b, c = b, c, d
        fmt.Println(a, b, c, d)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)

    // second try
    a = big.NewInt(1)
    b = big.NewInt(2)
    c = big.NewInt(3)
    d = big.NewInt(0)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        // d = a + b + c
        d = big.NewInt(0).Add(big.NewInt(0).Add(a, b), c)
        fmt.Println(a, b, c, d)
        // a <- b, b <- c, c <- d
        a, b, c = b, c, d
        fmt.Println(a, b, c, d)
    }

    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[math/big.NewInt](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewInt) returns a *pointer* to an `Int`, so after your first iteration, both `c` and `d` point to the **same** object. This means, in your second iteration, when you add something to `d`, the same change will be reflected in `c`. Then you copy `c` to `b` so `b` will also point to the same object, and on the next iteration `b` to `a`, so after your third iteration, all 4 variables point to the same `Int`.

Your second loop works because you create a new `Int` for `d` each time, so every time you shift the pointers, a *new* `Int` (the one which was created for `d`) gets moved to `c`, then to `b`, then to `a`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.